# create Site Definition and deployment steps with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, development

I have to create an **Site Definition**, To create the list, library and master page by default in the newly created sub-site.
I have to create all this with the custom Development(Visual Studio 2012).
**Does anybody done this previously?**